# Matrix vector multiplication inside summation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

I have an equation in the following form: $\sum_j A\bf{x}_j$

Where, 
$A$ - is a matrix and

$\bf{x}_j$ is a vector.

Can I write this equation in the following form?

$A\sum_j \bf{x}_j$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Matrix multiplication is linear; that is, $A(x_1 + x_2) = Ax_1 + Ax_2$ and $A(cx) = cAx$ where $c$ is a constant. Your desired expression is just an extension of the first property.